# Static stuff in a Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Why I shouldn't use static objects in an Activity or don't make static calls to an Activity?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that... As long as you don't give the static object a reference to anything that's not static in the Activity, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more reasonable statement would be saying be extremely careful about using static variables in Android.

You can use them, but be aware that you application can and will be killed by the OS, and restarted when the user returns to the app (i.e. maybe from the recent apps list).  This results in your application having many different entry points, and you can't assume the static variable will be initialized.

For example, setting a static variable in your application's first Activity, and assuming it will always be set is a big mistake.

Also, be cautious about storing anything that has a reference to an Activity as a static variable, because this tends to be a common source of consuming memory unnecessarily.  For example, storing a `View` in a static variable is almost certainly a mistake, because it will prevent an entire Activity from being garbage collected if not cleared out.

Comment: I've been really curious for some time as to why it is the case that static variables set in one Activity can be unset when another is in the foreground. Before discovering this, I was under the impression that static members wouldn't be garbage collected, and I can't think of another reason they might have been erased. Yet... you're right. They can be. (???)

Comment: While it is true that static variables won't be garbage collected, they can be reset if the OS kills your entire application to free memory. This is quite common, and can have many unforeseen consequences for developers, for example, the user could start your Application from some Activity other than your main Activity if they use the recent apps list or the back button.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general good practice to avoid making things static that don't need to be since they increase the chances of memory leaks. If you're always holding a reference to some data the GC won't be able to free it.